# Code size in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode3to4

How do I find out the size of each binary module is in Xcode 4?  Xcode3 had this info in the main screen, but it seems to be hidden somewhere in XCode4.  I'm interested in comparing the effects of different techniques on code size and execution speed.  To be precise, I'm talking about the column marked "Code" in XCode3, which shows each binary module's size; see image below:

[image]

Comment: I wonder if this is just gone... I need it too!

Answer (score 0):

On the left side of xcode, under the product tab, right click on your app and select show in finder. In finder, the size should be displayed on the right side of the file if you are in list mode. You can go into list mode by clicking the different view options in the top left of finder. That is how you find the binary size. If it doesn't show the binary size, right click on the product file in xcode and click compress. The file size should be showed to the left of the binary. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I mean each module, not the total file.  I've modified my question to add a screen image from XCode3 to be clearer.